# The import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

I am facing an issue with import org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts statement in Java Swing application.

I have added the external jar file for org.dyno.visual.swing.layouts, but still it shows me this error.

[image: Import Jar Issue]

Please let me know what should be done to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a package/packages known as "Visual Swing 4 Eclipse".

You can download the .zip file containing the necessary JAR files from http://visualswing4eclipse.googlecode.com/files/vs4e_0.9.12.I20090506-2220.zip.

Once downloaded, extract the ZIP file to somewhere inside your Eclipse project (into a folder like ExternalJARs or something).  Once their extracted there:

1. Right click on your Java project, and click "Properties".
2. On the left frame that comes up, click on "Java Build Path".
3. On the right frame, click on "Libraries".
4. You'll see a button on the right-most side of the window with the label "Add JARs...".  Click it
5. Open the Eclipse Java project and navigate to the folder where you extracted the .zip to.  Once there, you'll see a list of JAR files.  Select all of them (or just the ones you need), and click the "Ok" button.
6. Click the next "Ok" button again to return to your workspace.  You should notice the errors are now gone.  I they aren't, try to refresh your Java project in Eclipse, and the error messages should go away.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Those imports are from `org.dyno.visual.swing_0.9.12.I20090423-1800.jar`.

I used Visual Swing libraries in a project and I just added them to the BuildPath.
Now I converted this project to Maven and I was not able to find these libraries on any maven repository.
My solution was to add manually the libraries that I use to the local repository.

I added to `.m2\repository\org\dyno\visual\swing\0.9.12` the following files:

`swing-0.9.12.jar` (this is `org.dyno.visual.swing_0.9.12.I20090423-1800.jar` renamed)

`swing-0.9.12.pom` (I created this based on other pom files from repository)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.dyno.visual</groupId>
  <artifactId>swing</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.12</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>Visual Swing</name>
  <url>http://dyno.org/visual/swing/</url>
  <description></description>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>GNU General Public License, version 2</name>
      <url>http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
  </licenses>
</project>
```

In the project's pom I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.dyno.visual</groupId>
    <artifactId>swing</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

I hope this helps if you will need to use Visual Swing with Maven.